# Form1 datagridview selected row 3rd index data display on form2 labelbox

Tags: datagridview, label

I want to datagidview selected row 3rd index data will display on form2 labelbox without opening form1 .I use below code but it doesn't work..
and it give error

```
> Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of
> the collection. Parameter name: index
```

The form1 datagridview 3rd column is date i want that date display on form2 label

```
form2.Label.Text = form1.DataGridView1.Rows(form1.DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index).Cells(3).Value.ToString
```

Comment: you keep using the wrong tag, this also has to be Vb.NET code, not VB6.  CurrentRow  is not the same as Selected Row

Comment: okk..what is solution for that?